# Net MVC Telerik application gives UI issues in MS Edge

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, microsoft-edge, telerik-grid

Export to Excel of Telerik Kendo grid doesnt work in MS Edge. The feature works fine in Chrome and IE 11. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have just ran one of the demo's from the Kendo UI demo site and it worked fine in Edge. Please can you provide more information in terms of what isn't working? How your grid is set up etc.

Comment: Which kind of MS Edge version are you using? can you share us the detailed error message? I have checked [this demo](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/excel-export), it works well in Microsoft Edge 44 version, you could check whether it works or not. If it works, please compare the code with yours, and check the difference. Otherwise, please share your code and try to re-set the Edge setting or install the Microsoft Edge 44 version.

Answer (score 0):

ours is 42.17 version of MS Edge